# Switch pictures using UISwitch and NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I'm in a rut.. bagging for helping hands..

The code I'm working on is like this:

Once the switch on, displays the first picture and then appears the second picture when the switch off. if the switch on and off for three times, comes the third picture and fourth picture when the switch off. These course of process are expected to be repeated for five times. I put the pictures in the array. How can I make a use of NSMutableArray and UISwitch to bring my code alive...?

These are my trials:

```
-(IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender {

    if(_switchClick.isOn == YES)
    {
        NSMutableArray* pictureList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"songHae.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"pai.png"], nil];
        [_imageFrame setImage:[pictureList objectAtIndex:0]];

    }
    else
    {
        [_imageFrame setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lion.png"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your picture list outside of the switchAction handler, as well as a currentPictureIndex tracking variable.

```
int currentPictureIndex = 0;
```

Then in your handler you can do this:

```
[_imageFrame setImage:[pictureList objectAtIndex:currentPictureIndex++]];
if (currentPictureIndex >= pictureList.count) {
    currentPictureIndex = 0
}
```

This will make your picture change on every state change of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declared the array outside the function, so that need not to initialize it on every switch on/off and also need to initialize with more number of images (10 images) as you want to do it five times with different images.

```
int currentPictureIndex = 0;
int numberOfTries = 0;
-(IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender {

if(_switchClick.isOn == YES )
{
    [_imageFrame setImage:[pictureList objectAtIndex:currentPictureIndex]];
    numberOfTries++;

}
else
{
    [_imageFrame setImage:[pictureList objectAtIndex:currentPictureIndex+1]];
}
if(numberOfTries%3 == 0 )
{
   currentPictureIndex  = currentPictureIndex+2;
}
else if(pictureList.count==currentPictureIndex+2)
{
     currentPictureIndex = 0;
     numberOfTries = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: hold you in my great respect!